# Cannot persist an entity within an integration test using the MongoDB GORM plugin

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-plugin, gorm-mongodb

Context: 
I've created a new plugin named AppDomain that includes the Mongo 3.0.1 plugin. It has one domain class (Person), and one integration test (PersonSpec).

Issue:
The id is being generated. The appdomain database and person collection are being created in Mongo. However, the integration test is failing at the collection count.

Notes:
Having consulted all documentation that I could find and having made the bare minimum of changes to the generated AppDomain plugin code, I'm at a loss as to why the persistence test included here is failing. I have a similar plugin configured with grails 2.2.2 using junit tests that works just fine.

Any help is appreciated.

```
package appdomain

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

-

```
package appdomain

import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.mongodb.*
import spock.lang.*

@TestMixin(MongoDbTestMixin)
class PersonSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "can persist a person to the appdomain mongo database"() {
        given: "a person"
        def aPerson = new Person(firstName: "Homer", lastName: "Simpson")

        when: "the person is saved"
        aPerson.save()

        then: "the person has an id"
        aPerson.id != null //Passes

        and: "the Person collection contains one item"
        Person.list().size() == 1 //Fails with Person.list().size() == 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same result when you use findAll() or getAll() instead of list()?

Comment: I do @ÖzgürEroğlu. findAll() and getAll() fail in the same way. As does Person.count().

Comment: @JasonStonebraker, maybe you have some incorrect DB option in the config test environment? For example you DB is not created and `dbCreate = "validate"` or is absent. I think with mongo must exists similar prefrences.

Answer (score 1):

GORM doesn't always persist the object right after you call save.

[Official Reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) Says

> The save method informs the persistence context that an instance
>   should be saved or updated. The object will not be persisted
>   immediately unless the flush argument is used.

Therefore you should call save to flush the session immediately so that the changes take effect right away.

```
. . .
when: "the person is saved"
        aPerson.save(flush:true)
. . .
```

Sometimes, save fails (even if `flush:true` is supplied) due to validation or other non-common errors! If you want to get an Exception in these situations you should also add `failOnError:true` like this

```
. . .
when: "the person is saved"
        aPerson.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
. . .
```

Read more about save method in the [Official Reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) Page